# php json_decode() returns null

Tags: php, json, post

I have this string:

```
"{\"time\":1327220746000,\"long\":14.382638525754006,\"acc\":35,\"alt\":326,\"lat\":50.07442396194751}"
```

and while trying to parse it with json_decode in my php script, it only returns null..
This happens only on server, while trying it localy it returns the right object..

```
$string = $_POST['location'];
$location = json_decode($string);
```

The string above is exact var_dump of my $_POST['location'] field (without the String(length) part)
Any hints, how to debug that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have escaped quotes in your request variables. Try disabling `magic_quotes_gpc` in your server configuration or if is not possible run `stripslashes` on your variable before decoding it.

Comment: Yeah thank you, stripslashes function solved my problem..I really thought that would something with the slashes, so I ran it localy, but when it returned correct object, I was confused..So thanks, I will accept your answer once it will be 5 minutes old:)